# Details regarding mixing grounds from different panels

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

I read in other Questions here that grounds from different panels should not be comingled unless conduit is providing the ground.   To very briefly summarize the reason: under certain failure scenarios, a ground wire can end up carrying much more current than it should with no *suitable* breaker to protect it.

My question is: what approach to take if circuits from different panels end up in the same junction box?

- Have I misunderstood, does the rule to keep grounds separated only apply to retrofitting grounds, or does it apply also when cables *with grounds* come into a box from different panels?
- What if you the box is metal, what do you do with the grounds?  Are you required to add a new separate box in these situations or can you mix them?
- What if the box is not metal, but the ground wires are bare?  Should you connect all the grounds from each panel separately and take steps to ensure they stay separate? EG use  divider?

Comment: Having power in the same box from two different panels is probably not the best idea.  If at all possible should keep both panels separate, someone who does not know about the second panel, is not going to be happy.  I would be more concern to keep the neutrals(if all white) separate, than worry too much about the grounds.  If all the grounds are connected together, then the right breaker should work

Comment: Yes, how to manage neutrals is covered very well in other Questions so let's avoid that here.   I agree that it would be better to avoid the situation.   But there are some scenarios where it arises.    In my case, "does not know about" is not a problem.  The two panels are right next to each other, and all the cables from throughout the house are obviously spread between them somewhat randomly.  You can't be unaware of the situation.   I may one day rearrange the circuits so one of the panels is "critical loads" but that will probably make this question FAR more pertinent.

Comment: For the time being I have mixed panels, as far as I know, in only one box throughout the whole house and it wouldn't be too hard to change that ... so I guess a sub-question is how badly I ought to do that.

Comment: I think most code tries to do away with two separate breakers to the same junction/outlet box, unless both breakers can be tied together.  The early MBWC did not do that and people were not happy afterwards with having their fingers fried.  You will stay there forever and remember the two breakers, but the next person won't.

Comment: Are your "panels" both subpanels of the same service, or are they each main panels for a separate service? If the former, grounds from either would be connected together at the main service panel already.

Comment: @crip659 nothing wrong with two different breakers in one box. Happens all the time in kitchens and bathrooms. Just can't combine on same yoke.

Comment: @Armand they are both main panels from the same service.  A 200A and a 100A panel split from a 320A meter.  They are right next to each other, connected by conduits and they share their ground rod.

Answer (score 2):

Separating systems when possible is good practice, but when not practical the NEC is pretty clear on the requirement here:

> 250.148 Continuity of Equipment Grounding Conductors and Attachment in Boxes. If circuit conductors are spliced within a box or terminated on
> equipment within or supported by a box, **all wire-type equipment
> grounding conductor(s) associated with any of those circuit conductors
> shall be connected within the box** or to the box in accordance with
> 250.8 and 250.148(A) through (D)
>
> (A) Connections and Splices. Connections and splices shall be made in
> accordance with 110.14(B) except that insulation shall not be
> required.
>
> (B) Equipment Grounding Conductor Continuity. The arrangement of
> grounding connections shall be such that the disconnection or the
> removal of a luminaire, receptacle, or other device fed from the box
> does not interrupt the electrical continuity of the equipment
> grounding conductor(s) providing an effective ground-fault current
> path.
>
> (C) Metal Boxes. A connection used for no other purpose shall be made
> between the metal box and the equipment grounding conductor(s) in
> accordance with 250.8.
>
> (D) Nonmetallic Boxes. One or more equipment grounding conductors
> brought into a nonmetallic outlet box shall be arranged such that a
> connection can be made to any fitting or device in that box requiring
> connection to an equipment grounding conductor.

(I have not omitted any text containing exceptions.)

(Edit) Also see Section 300.3(C) Conductors of Different Systems

> (1) 1000 Volts ac, 1500 volts dc, Nominal, or Less. Conductors of ac
> and dc circuits rated 1000 volts ac, 1500 volts dc, nominal, or less,
> shall be permitted to occupy the same equipment wiring enclosure,
> cable, or raceway. All conductors shall have an insulation rating
> equal to at least the maximum circuit voltage applied to any conductor
> within the enclosure, cable, or raceway.

I will address each statement question you asked.

I read in other Questions here that grounds from different panels should not be comingled unless conduit is providing the ground To very briefly summarize the reason: under certain failure scenarios, a ground wire can end up carrying much more current than it should with no suitable breaker to protect it.

*Breakers have a fault rating separate from overcurrent rating that is sized to the maximum current available at the panel. The size of the transformers normally used for residential services limits this fault current to less than the 10,000 amp minimum rating of breakers available.*

My question is: what approach to take if circuits from different panels end up in the same junction box?

*Connect all grounds (1)together and to the box if metal, or (2) all to the metal box by 250.8 approved method.*

Have I misunderstood, does the rule to keep grounds separated only apply to retrofitting grounds, or does it apply also when cables with grounds come into a box from different panels?

*I think you have misunderstood. When retrofitting a ground it isn't even necessary to run the retrofit ground from the panel, you can run to various points on the grounding electrode system, but if you do run to a panel it must be the source panel so that in the future removal of panel doesn't lose ground. Imagine circuit is run from main panel but ground to a subpanel and the subpanel gets removed.*

What if you the box is metal, what do you do with the grounds? Connect. Are you required to add a new separate box in these situations or can you mix them?

*The practical method is to connect all grounds together and that connection to the box via ground screw or clip. Alternately in a large box with multiple grounds each ground wire can be connected to the box via 250.8 listed method.*

What if the box is not metal, but the ground wires are bare? Should you connect all the grounds from each panel separately and take steps to ensure they stay separate? EG use divider?

*I'm not clear on this, I think a box divider in a plastic box would qualify as a separate enclosure, but I only use metal boxes when box dividers are needed.*

Comment: These are good points to be reminded of regardless of whether you have gorunds from multiple panels, but I don't see how they address the Question.  Are you saying that implicitly, these are ALL the requirements, so if you have grounds from two panels in a junction box and you comply with all the above, there are no other concerns? I don't think that's what you're saying.

Comment: And this is the correct answer. You must splice all the safety grounds in boxes served out of different panels.

Comment: I am trying to show that the code allows multiple circuits from multiple sources in a junction box and that when the circuit conductors are spliced *"all wire-type equipment grounding conductor(s) associated with any of those circuit conductors shall be connected within the box"*.